# Form link (button) not firing

Tags: html

I am working with this piece of code and it is not firing when I put it in the page need which is static HTML. It does work if you create a plain HTML page, but it is not working on the page I need.

What could it be?

```
    <form name="CTTPDD" action="https://example.com" method="post" target="_blank">

    <input type="hidden" value="##.##" name="campaign" />

    <input name="repeat" type="hidden" value="1">

    <input type="image" src="image.gif" value="submit" name="submit" />

    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have
    `<input type="image" src="image.gif" value="submit" name="submit" />`
I think really should say    `<input type="image" src="image.gif" name="submit" />` Your problem was your    `value="Submit` was saying that the image should say which will mess every thing up.

Comment: Yep but it doesn't fire it just shows the image and when you hover over it it show the link hand and thats all.